# JavaFX 2.0 - How to change legend color of a LineChart dynamically?

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to style my JavaFX linechart but I have some trouble with the legend.

I know how to change the legend color of a line chart in the css file:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke:  #FF0000, white; } 
.default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke:  #00FF00, white; }
.default-color2.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke:  #0000FF, white; }
.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #FF0000, white; }
.default-color1.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #00FF00, white; } 
.default-color2.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #0000FF, white; }
```

But this is not enough for my purposes. I have three or more colored toggle buttons and a series of data for every button. The data should be displayed in the same color the button has after I have selected the button. This should be possible with a multiselection of the buttons, so that more than one series of data can be displayed simultaneously.

For the chart lines I have managed it by changing the style after I clicked the button:

```
..
dataList.add(series); 
..
series.getNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke: rgba(" + rgba + ")");
```

If I deselect the button I remove the data from the list.

```
dataList.remove(series);
```

That is working fine for the strokes, but how can I do the same for the legend?

You can see an example below. First I clicked the red button, thus the stroke and the legend is red (default-color0). After that I clicked the blue button. Here you can see the problem. The stroke is blue but the legend is green, because default color1 is used and I do not know how to change the legend color.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean subtitle or label?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue as well. The issue seems to be that when data series are added to the chart, the legend isn't updated at the same time, so when you lookup components with that seriesN style class they don't exist yet. Came up with a work-around that detects when the legend items are created so that dynamic styling can be added to them.

I added a ListChangeListener to the chart legend's "getChildrenUnmodifiable()" ObservableList, which in turn adds a ListChangeListener to each of the legend's children as they get added. From within this listener, we can tell when new items are being added to the legend (or removed). This allow us to then make the dynamic style changes.

```
for (Node n : lineChart.getChildrenUnmodifiable())
    {
        if (n instanceof Legend)
        {
            final Legend legend = (Legend) n;

            // remove the legend
            legend.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<?> arg0)
                {
                    for (Node node : legend.getChildrenUnmodifiable())
                    {
                        if (node instanceof Label)
                        {
                            final Label label = (Label) node;
                            label.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onChanged(Change<?> arg0)
                                {
                                    //make style changes here
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: A thousand thanks for this, I was looking for something like that for days.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but to what I'll add the style changes? to label? @MaxD

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, this problem can be solved by wrapping your relevant code in a call to `Platform.runLater()`. For example:

```
LineChart<Number, Number> plot;
....
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    Node nl = plot.lookup(".default-color0.chart-series-line");
    Node ns = plot.lookup(".default-color0.chart-line-symbol");

    nl.setStyle("-fx-stroke: #333;");
    ns.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #333, white;");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Where can I find all these cryptic css for JavaFX?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator This is what I use as reference https://gist.github.com/tmazeika/c90c03c645d18722ddb0

Comment: what is this plot.lookup?

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu I have adjusted my example. Plot is the LineChart element

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on @Chris' solution

```
 if (checkCombo.getCheckModel().isChecked(0)) {
    lineChart.getData().add(seriesTest1);
    changeColorSeries(lineChart.getData().size() - 1, "darkgreen");
 }

 if (checkCombo.getCheckModel().isChecked(3)) {
    lineChart.getData().add(seriesTest2);
    changeColorSeries(lineChart.getData().size() - 1, "darkred");
 }

 private void changeColor(int position, String color) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Node nl = lineChart.lookup(".default-color" + position + ".chart-series-line");
            Node ns = lineChart.lookup(".default-color" + position + ".chart-line-symbol");
            Node nsl = lineChart.lookup(".default-color" + position + ".chart-legend-item-symbol");

            nl.setStyle("-fx-stroke: " + color + ";");
            ns.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + color + ", white;");
            nsl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + color + ", white;");
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging a lot through google with no success I finally found a lean way to update the legend colors according line color through this method:

```
private void setLegendItemColor(String shop, String color, Legend lg) {
        for (Node n : lg.getChildren()) {
                Label lb = (Label) n;
                if (lb.getText().contains(shop)) {
                    lb.getGraphic().setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + color + ";");
                }
        }
}
```

So you just need to call the method setLegendItemColor() when you´re going to update the chart lines to update the legend label symbols to the correspondent color.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197877/javafx-linechart-legend-style) guy is able to lookup the nodes used for legend using their class, and then calling setStyle() on those nodes. (I don't think his problem is relevant for yours)