# JavaFX StackedBarChart legend color don't follow chart color CSS styled

Tags: css, charts, javafx, legend

In my application (JDK 1.8u51) I want to set some specific colors to some data categories in a StackedBarChart. I made this with a CSS as bellow :

```
.root{
    -fx-ok-color: darkgreen;
    -fx-critical-color: darkblue;
    -fx-warning-color: gold;
    -fx-minor-color: orange;
    -fx-major-color: red;
    -fx-undefined-color: darkgrey;  
}
.okChartBar{
    -fx-bar-fill : -fx-ok-color;
}
.warnigChartBar{
    -fx-bar-fill : -fx-warning-color;
}
.minorChartBar{
    -fx-bar-fill : -fx-minor-color;
}
.majorChartbar{
    -fx-bar-fill : -fx-major-color;
}
.criticalChartBar{
    -fx-bar-fill : -fx-critical-color;
}
.undefinedChartBar{
    -fx-bar-fill : -fx-undefined-color;
}
```

I use this CSS in my code like this :

```
StackedBarChart barChart = new StackedBarChart(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());
barChart.setTitle("Title");
vBox.getChildren().add(1,barChart);
barChart.setAnimated(true);
barChart.getData().addAll(barChartData());
barChart.getData().forEach(data ->{
    XYChart.Series moduleSerie = (XYChart.Series)data;
    moduleSerie.getData().forEach(item ->{
        XYChart.Data item2 = (XYChart.Data)item;
        item2.getNode().getStyleClass().add(styleLink.get(moduleSerie.getName())); 
        // styleLink is a map which containt the link from the alarm type (minor, major....) to the CSS style   (minorChartbar, majorChartbar, ...)
    });
});
```

What I get as reslut to this is such a StackedBarChart :
[image: Example of not same color between chart and legend]

As you can see, the colors between the chart areas and the legend aren't the same. "Critical" value must be Blue and "Major" must be Red.

Is it a JavaFX bug or is it just my code?

Sorry for the long post, I just want to be as complete as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who search I found the answer on 2 other questions :

- [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622709/javafx-2-0-how-to-change-legend-color-of-a-linechart-dynamically)
- [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197877/javafx-linechart-legend-style)

I also had to add `.chart-legend-item-symbol` into each style class in my CSS like this :

```
.okChartBar .chart-legend-item-symbol{ 
    -fx-background-color:-fx-ok-color;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue but that code fragment in both answers didnt work for me can you help?