# JavaFX LineChart Dynamically Change Legend Color

Tags: java, javafx, charts, linechart

I am trying to change the color of the legend dynamically, so I dont have any style for lines and symbols in my css class. I can change all lines and symbols in chart dynamically but cant change legend sadly. They stay default. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

So, What I've Tried:

**1)**

```
for (int index = 0; index < series.getData().size(); index++) {
    XYChart.Data dataPoint = series.getData().get(index);
    Node lineSymbol = dataPoint.getNode().lookup(".chart-legend");
    lineSymbol.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00ff00, #000000; -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;\n" +
            "    -fx-background-radius: 3px;\n" +
            "    -fx-padding: 3px;");
}
```

according to caspian.css and linked questions below, this should work but it gives me **NullPointerException** because cant find .chart-legend even though its there.

**2)**

```
for (Node n : lineChart.getChildrenUnmodifiable())
{
    if (n instanceof Legend)
    {
        final Legend legend = (Legend) n;

        // remove the legend
        legend.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<?> arg0)
            {
                for (Node node : legend.getChildrenUnmodifiable())
                {
                    if (node instanceof Label)
                    {
                        final Label label = (Label) node;
                        label.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onChanged(Change<?> arg0)
                            {
                                //make style changes here
                            }

                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This didnt do anything either and slowed the program like hell.

**3)**

```
   int index = 2;
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myChart.lookupAll(".chart-legend-item-symbol").toArray()[index].setStyle("-fx-border-color: rgba(200,0,0,1)");
}});
```

This either didnt do anything.

Any help would be appriciated.

I looked at all of these but they didnt help:

[JavaFX StackedBarChart legend color don't follow chart color CSS styled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944950/javafx-stackedbarchart-legend-color-dont-follow-chart-color-css-styled)

[JavaFX 2.0 - How to change legend color of a LineChart dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622709/javafx-2-0-how-to-change-legend-color-of-a-linechart-dynamically)

[JavaFX LineChart legend style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197877/javafx-linechart-legend-style)

**EDIT: THIS IS THE SOLUTION I FOUND**

None of this worked for me so, I found another solution. Neither the answer nor the Platform.runLater method.

```
XYChart.Series<Number,Number> value  //is our serie value.

for(int index = 0; index<value.getData().size(); index++){
    // we're looping for each data point, changing the color of line symbol
    XYChart.Data dataPoint = value.getData().get(index);
    Node lineSymbol = dataPoint.getNode().lookup(".chart-line-symbol");
    lineSymbol.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #0000FF, white;");
}
// and this is for the color of the line
value.getNode().setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-stroke: #0000FF; -fx-background-color: #0000FF;");
```

For Legend Color changing:

```
for(Node n : chart.getChildrenUnmodifiable()){
   if(n instanceof Legend){
      for(Legend.LegendItem legendItem : ((Legend)n).getItems()){
        legendItem.getSymbol().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #0000ff, white;");
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this works for anyone searching for this too.

**EDIT to Moderator**: This is flagged as duplicate but this question is mainly about LineChart's Legends' because they are not updated as they should although the series colours are changing. The duplicate question is just about changing series' colours. This question is about legends of those items.

Comment: @kleopatra there is actually.

Comment: no there isn't (at least I can't see any ;), you are showing mere snippets without context - please read the referenced help page to understand what's required ..

Comment: More than this is uploading project to github including pom.xml and main class. The all required code is there and by writing a Junit test with including the dependency, someone can reproduce the whole situation shown.

Comment: repeating: read the referenced help page .. it's _always_ possible to create a stand-alone, minimal example - nobody want's to wade through tons of unrelated code nor guess both problem and solutions, particularly not future reader looking for help (who are at the focus of this site)

Answer (score 5):

It works for me just to change the looked-up color names `CHART_COLOR_x` where `x` is the (1-based) index of the series.

I.e. just do

```
chart.setStyle("CHART_COLOR_1: #ff0000 ; CHART_COLOR_2: #0000FF ;");
```

to set the color of the first series (line, points, and legend) to red, and the color of the second series to blue.

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DynamicLinechart extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());

        Series<Number, Number> series1 = new Series<>();
        series1.setName("Data set 1");

        Series<Number, Number> series2 = new Series<>();
        series2.setName("Data set 2");

        chart.getData().add(series1);
        chart.getData().add(series2);

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 20 ; i++) {
            series1.getData().add(new Data<>(i, rng.nextInt(100)));
            series2.getData().add(new Data<>(i, rng.nextInt(100)));
        }

        ColorPicker picker1 = new ColorPicker();
        ColorPicker picker2 = new ColorPicker();

        ChangeListener<Color> listener = (obs, oldColor, newColor) -> 
            updateStyles(chart, picker1.getValue(), picker2.getValue());

        picker1.valueProperty().addListener(listener);
        picker2.valueProperty().addListener(listener);

        picker1.setValue(Color.RED);
        picker2.setValue(Color.BLUE);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(chart);
        HBox controls = new HBox(5, picker1, picker2);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        root.setTop(controls);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateStyles(Node node, Color color1, Color color2) {
        node.setStyle(String.format("CHART_COLOR_1: %s ; CHART_COLOR_2: %s ;", format(color1), format(color2))); 
    }

    private String format(Color c) {
        int r = (int) (255 * c.getRed()) ;
        int g = (int) (255 * c.getGreen()) ;
        int b = (int) (255 * c.getBlue()) ;

        return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want a little more control (and perhaps a little more robustness), define your own looked-up colors, and modify those. I.e. in an external CSS file, do something like

```css
.root {
    -data-color-1: red ;
    -data-color-2: blue ;
}
.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: -data-color-1, white; }
.default-color1.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: -data-color-2, white; }
.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: -data-color-1; }
.default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: -data-color-2; }
```

And now just update the values of the looked-up colors you defined:

```
private void updateStyles(Node node, Color color1, Color color2) {
    node.setStyle(String.format("-data-color-1: %s ; -data-color-2: %s ;", format(color1), format(color2))); 
}
```

Comment: Because I want it to go dynamical, it shouldnt work with css this much. There are 30-40 lines on the screen sometimes and some should have standard colors, some shouldn't, they should stay random colors. So sadly this didnt work for me when I tried it before as I linked all the questions I looked. But @Sedrick 's answer from here works: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369495/javafx-barchart-set-series-color-by-series-name/44371947#comment75745727_44371947

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu I don't really understand that comment. This is "dynamical" - in any possible sense I can understand. The color is chosen by the Java code, and can be changed at runtime as the demo clearly shows. Why use a complex solution when you can use a simple one, which is the way the toolkit was intended to be used.

Comment: What I am trying to say is I only make the user choose 8 different lines from settings menu, but I've around 30-40 lines, so for the rest of them it should be randomized and I wont be using any css. What I wanted was in the link where Sedrick answered but problem solved anyways.

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu OK, but it would have been nice if you had explained in the question that that was what you wanted.

Comment: @James_D This answer should have more points - many thanks!